# Column values to colnames and rownames in R

Tags: r

I am trying to put the following date into a different format but running into a few errors.

I am trying to create a matrix where the data will hopefully look as the following

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am working though it now but when I apply;

`test <- reshape(specificity, idvar = "Region", timevar = "Sector", direction = "wide")`    I get errors

Comment: You need to start with a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix` - `reshape(data.frame(specificity), idvar="Region", timevar="Sector", direction="wide")`

Comment: Thanks so much!, been working on this all night and I finally have the results I want :) thanks!!

Comment: It might be worth going back to the import of your data and making sure you have a `data.frame` right from the start, with distinct numeric and character columns. Might make it easier to work with generally